# Overriding a Unity registration using configuration?

Tags: c#, unity-container

Can I override a registration defined in code with a 'mapping' in the web config?

I've read many tutorials that cover registrations that can be done in either the an config or code but none (so far) that use both.

My situation is based on Azure. Locally, I want to register an interface that resolves to a file based provider while in the cloud, a storage based one.

Is this possible or am I going to have to write the logic into the code based registration to determine which type to resolve for the interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can override manual registrations with configuration and vice versa. Unity allows you to override mappings and it doesn't care what is the source of the information.

```
container.RegisterType( ... );
container.LoadConfiguration(); // override with configuration
container.RegisterType( ... ); // override once again, this time with manual mapping
```

Comment: This is the one.  I wasn't expecting to have to load the configuration manually.  Also, this method is only available through the extensions so didn't spot it before.